# facebook app in a page tab - How to get callback URL

Tags: php, facebook

I am a bit of a catch 22 situation here.

When you load your app into a tab and ask for permission you need to send with it a callback url.

The callback url is a bit of a mission because on a page `http://www.facebook.com/pages/<PAEG NAME>/<PAGE ID>?sk=app_<APP ID>` the only way to get the `<PAGE ID>` is to get it out of the signed request:

```
parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], $APPSecret)
```

which you can only do when the user has given permission. And you need the ID to be able to get the `<PAGE NAME>`, which basically means I cannot construct the callback url...

Does anyone know of a better way or different way to Ask for permissions immediately as the page loads and then reload the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are a bit confused, here are some points:

1. Your callback (redirect) url should be something relative (or identical) to the Tab url you specify in the application settings. Something like:

   ```
   http://www.example.com/canvas/tab/index.php
   ```

   So no need for the page id.
2. Even if the page id is **not** needed, you'll still receive it (even without authorization) in the `signed_request`!
   Read the [Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#tabs) related section carefully:

> When a user selects your Page Tab, you
>   will received the `signed_request`
>   parameter with **one additional
>   parameter, `page`. This parameter
>   contains a JSON object with an `id` (the
>   page id of the current page)**, `admin`
>   (if the user is a admin of the page),
>   and `liked` (if the user has liked the
>   page). As with a Canvas Page, **you will
>   not receive all the user information
>   accessible to your app in the
>   `signed_request` until the user
>   authorizes your app.**

So the thing that you'll not receive is the USER ID not the page id which is kind of obvious since the admin "*allowed*" the application.

Hope this will clear things out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript SDK

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

And use this allow dialog

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

This way you don't even need to refresh.

Also, you can get **page_id** in signed_request even without user allowing it. You're talking about **user_id** and **oauth_token** which won't get passed unless signed-in user doesn't allow your app.